# Views are loaded in opposite order than nested LoadViewModel calls in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross

I'm working on a tablet/desktop app and currently face a problem with nested LoadViewModel calls:

- Some of the views/viewmodels show live data. For the case that there is no network connectivity there is a separate "offline" viewmodel which is loaded by the live viewmodel and will close itself once we are online again. This works fine unless we are offline at the time the "live" viewmodel gets loaded. In this case I am trying to load the "offline" viewmodel during the initialization of the "live" viewmodel. Unfortunately the "offline" view is presented first, followed by the "live" view (even though the LoadViewModel calls where in the opposite order). Since these views are presented in the same window region the "live" view is shown instead of the "offline" view.
- At another place there is a typical master detail interface. There I ran into the very same problem. If I try to preselect a list entry of the master view this logically causes a LoadViewModel call for the corresponding detail view. Again, the detail view is loaded before the master view gets loaded. This is a problem for my presenter since the master view acts as container for the detail view, (I know, with the MultiRegionPresenter used in Stuard's examples this is working but there you cannot have detail viewmodels which do not always have the same number of sub-viewmodels.)

Maybe I got something wrong and there is a better way of doing this? Or is there an easy way to ensure that the Views are loaded in the same order as LoadViewModel was called?

**Edit:**
Thanks a lot for all the speedy replies! Best start for an example would be the Twitter Search example (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch) which unfortunately does not seem to fully work anymore :-(. Anyway, it might not matter that much to explain what I tried to do. If you change the constructor of HomeViewModel to call SearchCommand() and place a breakpoint inside Present(...) of MultiRegionPresenter of the TwitterSearch.UI.Wpf project the breakpoint is hit for TwitterView (which is our "detail view") first even though HomeViewModel was the model loaded first. Is there another or a better way to get TwitterViewModel loaded immediately when HomeViewModel is loaded?

Comment: Could you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) of your code, might be easier to answer if we can see how you are doing this. Cheers!

Comment: My question is, what's functionally different between the offline/live VMs/views - can you not load one or the other instead of loading both and then swap if the data comes online?

Comment: Some example code might certainly help here. It feels like the problem might be that you are perhaps performing loading/showing of new views/viewmodels synchronously during the loading/showing of views/viewmodels. If you could post some sample code of your presentation (maybe modifying an existing sample), it might be easier to comment and to suggest other events you can use for loading secondary views (after the first loads/shows have completed)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would need a different view model when there is no network connection, or in your 'offline' mode. In MVVM, we use one view model per view. Keep it simple and your problems will disappear. Surely when you're offline, you'll just show a message at on top of empty UI controls?

Either way, I would strongly recommend that you put whatever properties and/or functionality from your offline view model into your standard online view model.

Comment: Actually, that was my attempt to keep things simple ;-) Otherwise, for showing the progress of re-establishing the connection would have to be put in some kind of overlay and I would have to implement that on every single platform.